# FastAPI throws error "value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)" but inserts data in DB

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

POST throws me an error: value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict). What is wrong with my code?? It does however insert data in the DB despite the error.

My models.py:

```
class Checkpoint(BaseModel):
    Name: str
    Latitude: float
    Longitude: float
```

crud.py:

```
async def fetch_one_checkpoint(name):
    document = await collections.find_one({'Name': name})
    return document


async def fetch_all_checkpoints():
    checkpoints = []
    cursor = collections.find()
    async for document in cursor:
        checkpoints.append(Checkpoint(**document))
    return checkpoints


async def create_checkpoint(checkpoint):
    document = checkpoint
    result = await collections.insert_one(document)
    return result


async def update_checkpoint(name, lat, lon):
    await collections.update_one({'name': name}, {"$set": {'Latitude': lat}})
    await collections.update_one({'name': name}, {"$set": {'Longitude': lon}})
    document = await collections.find_one({'name': name})
    return document


async def remove_checkpoint(name):
    await collections.delete_one({'name': name})
    return True
```

main.py:

```
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {'Hello': 'World'}


@app.get("/api/checkpoint")
async def get_checkpoint():
    response = await fetch_all_checkpoints()
    return response


@app.get("/api/checkpoint{name}", response_model=Checkpoint)
async def get_checkpoint_by_id(name):
    response = await fetch_one_checkpoint(name)
    if response:
        return response
    raise HTTPException(404, f"There is no checkpoint: {name}")


@app.post("/api/checkpoint", response_model=Checkpoint)
async def post_checkpoint(checkpoint: Checkpoint):
    response = await create_checkpoint(checkpoint.dict())
    if response:
        return response
    raise HTTPException(400, "Something went wrong / Bad request")


@app.put("/api/checkpoint{name}", response_model=Checkpoint)
async def put_checkpoint(name: str, lat: float, lon: float):
    response = await update_checkpoint(name, lat, lon)
    if response:
        return response
    raise HTTPException(404, f"There is no checkpoint: {name}")


@app.delete("/api/checkpoint{name}", response_model=Checkpoint)
async def delete_checkpoint(name):
    response = await remove_checkpoint(name)
    if response:
        return "Successfully deleted checkpoint"
```

I have tried to change:

checkpoint.dict()

In:

```
@app.post("/api/checkpoint", response_model=Checkpoint)
async def post_checkpoint(checkpoint: Checkpoint):
    response = await create_checkpoint(checkpoint.dict())
    if response:
        return response
    raise HTTPException(400, "Something went wrong / Bad request")
```

To `dict(checkpoint)` and `checkpoint.json()` as well, but it didn't work in any such cases

Comment: It seems issue is with `return response`. Looks like `response` object is not a dict type object.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you @MaNKuR

I didn't take into account that collections.insert_one(document) wasn't a dict object